# Reading Query Parameters after # in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express

All,

I am using node. I want to read access token from url given below

```
http://localhost:3000/fb_code?#access_token=EAAEIchjA4AIBANjPw4wWExOFZBHoZCF6NnTnkVtvsJmrsBdeBn5268WMmr5KCE3nN50Aoaf1ZANyeQtdiKSbAydfHFmHXbt72i3iubKRoTLot2MlLNip6WmQL7ovVWTbij0VeZBLF7lvYour8TlKtcECPDIfZBaCefLwkjcfPpgZDZD&expires_in=5016
```

As there is a # in URL I cant read access_token as query parameter. If I try to prints req.query it prints a blank JSON ({}).

Regards

Comment: Hash and anything after it is not send to server, you can't read it.

Comment: It can be done if you can replace `#`  to `percent encoding`  and value of `#` is `%23`